# Why this error is coming while using numpy and jit

Tags: python, numpy, numba, jit

I am trying to run this code but it is throwing error that:
Failed in nopython mode pipeline

If I am running this with @jit it working but not with jit.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def np_clean(data):
    data[:, 0] = np.char.replace(data[:, 0].astype('U'), '-I.NFO', '-I')
    data = data[np.char.endswith(data[:, 0].astype('U'), '-I')]
    data = data[~np.char.find(data[:, 0].astype('U'), 'NIFTY')]
    data[:, 1] = np.char.replace(data[:, 1].astype('U'), '-', '/')
    data[:, 2] = [i[:-2]+'00'for i in data[:, 2]]
    return data

np_clean(df.values)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type array(pyobject, 2d, F)
During: typing of argument at C:\Users\caaka\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12896/1978023246.py (4)

File "..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12896\1978023246.py", line 4:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code ?

Comment: The input type is `array(pyobject, 2d, F)` which means items are objects. Objects are not supported by Numba because it needs to operate on native types and not on dynamic objects of the CPython interpreter. Besides, strings are barely supported by Numba: many functions are not implemented on them and the one that that are implemented are very slow. There is no plan to make that faster any time soon. THis is an exemple where Numba is nearly useless. Please read the doc about this for more information (eg. the first page).

Comment: Even if it was possible to compile it with Numba, the only explicit loop is in the last line. Perhaps, you could `njit` only that part, if anything (but not like this as comprehension are not supported) provided that the items are supported by Numba.